# Unexpected keyword argument 'verbose' : scipy curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use the simple curve_fit function in scipy.optimize package. The following is a command for fitting a curve to the gaussian function, but I want to see the progress as it fits, so I use verbose = 2 in curve_fit.

```
poptb, pcov = curve_fit(gaussian,cno,bkg[350:650],p0=[1000,100,bkg_peak1,3000],verbose=2)
```

Somehow, everytime I get this following error,

```
TypeError: leastsq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'
```

Comment: The errors says that the function `scipy.optimize.leastsq()` that has the problem.. not `curve_fit()` and the reason, according to [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) , is that this function doesn't have `verbose` parameter in its definition

Comment: Thank you, I was getting confused with `leastsq()` and `least_squares()`. While the former has no `verbose` parameter, the latter has one. It turns `method ='lm'` (which is the default) is used in `curve_fit()` it calls `leastsq()` but otherwise calls for `least_squares()`.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=None, sigma=None, absolute_sigma=False, check_finite=True, bounds=(-inf, inf), method=None, jac=None, **kwargs)[source]
```

As you can see, there is no 'verbose' parameter in v1.2.0

Comment: Thank you, I was getting confused with `leastsq()` and `least_squares()`. While the former has no `verbose` parameter, the latter has one. It turns `method ='lm'` (which is the default) is used in `curve_fit()` it calls `leastsq()` but otherwise calls for `least_squares()`.